# Unity 2d Low quality when using Tiled

Tags: unity-game-engine, tiled

I want to make my own game 2D using Unity and I want to edit maps using tiled, but when I use tiled I get low quality I don't know how to get good quality.

[image]

settings sprite
[image]

Comment: Please include an image of the import settings on the sprite.

Comment: @BrandonMiller i think problem from tiled na ?

Comment: There is only one element in the sprite as far as I can see, which is the tree. Setting your sprite mode to something other than "multiple" may help. Unless you are indeed using an atlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open map file in text editor and find this tline:

```
<tileset firstgid=“1” name=“Tileset” tilewidth=“32” tileheight=“32” spacing=“2” margin=“1” tilecount=“364” columns=“26”>
```

Change spacing and margin values to 0

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Extrude edges, Filter Mode, and Compression("Format", "Compressor Quality").

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings:

- Generate Mip Maps: Disabled
- Filter Mode: Point (no filter)
- Compression: None